# Factoring polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I want to factorising the polynomial x^2 - px - qx + pq by using Factor[x^2 - px - qx + pq], the result shows pq - px - qx + x^2. the result should be (x-p)(x-q), how to do it?

Comment: Put spaces between your variables to indicate multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Chip has it right.. Simply:

```
 Factor[x^2 - p*x - q*x + p*q]

 =(p - x) (q - x)
```

Or you don't have to use *, but make sure you put spaces in between your variables:

```
 Factor[x^2 - p x - q x + p q]

 =(p - x) (q - x)
```